# How to Automatically Block the Use of Link Shorteners in Marketing Cloud Email Triggers

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have a lot of users in our Marketing Cloud and we can't control that all the shots are going out without using a shortener (which hurts one of Validity's policies).

Is there any way we can automatically block shots that are using a shortener?

Comment: You can use ampscript / SSJS to filter out for any links that uses 'bit.ly' and then use RaiseError to stop from sending/ preview&testing email.

Comment: But how would I go through the body of the email looking for that link? If you have to create a manual scan it won't be scalable, you know? Then I need it to be something automatic.

Comment: there is no OOTB feature that would prohibit text from being included in an email, You would need to use approvals to control this

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have enough people to approve every email that is fired, we have many areas with autonomy and include this part in the complete bring process (and it still wouldn't be foolproof as validation is human). Even so, thank you very much for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Does your account have SAP setup? If so, wouldn't the shortened links be wrapped in your SAP domain?

For example, `bitly.com/xxrrr` would become `click.yoursapdomain.com/vsfsvsf`, essentially making all your links the same domain. Or is Validity looking at the redirected URL and penalizing you if it's a shortened link?